# phonegap run ios --device --verbose Error

Tags: ios, cordova, web-applications, phonegap-build

I used phonegap to install an app to an iPad yesterday simply using:

```
phonegap run ios
```

From within the project directory. I tried installing it to a second iPad today but that command did nothing. I then typed:

```
phonegap run ios --device --verbose
```

And got:

```
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “***” were found.

CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.4'


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:

Check dependencies
(1 failure)

Command finished with error code 65: /Users/.../.../.../MyApp/MyApp/platforms/ios/cordova/run --device

ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /Users/.../.../.../MyApp/MyApp/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 65
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

I do not get what is different from yesterday except the device plugged in?

Comment: A note, I am using Phonegap 5.2.2 and Cordova 5.1.1.

Comment: It clearly says that it ins't finding the code signing identities. Did you download and installed them? Open the app on xcode (it's on /platforms/ios) and run it, it should detect code signing errors and try to fix them